# Rellenar listas con datos de un CSV automáticamente

Tags: python-3.x

Estoy manipulando archivos *.csv*.
Tengo que recorrer cada columna de datos numéricos del archivo e introducirlas en diferentes listas.
El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
import csv

salto_linea = "\n"
csv_file = "02_CSV_data1.csv"

with open(csv_file, 'r') as csv_doc:    
    doc_reader = csv.reader(csv_doc, delimiter = ",")   
    mpg = []
    cylinders = []
    displacement = []
    horsepower = []
    weight = []
    acceleration = []
    year = []
    origin = []
    lt = [mpg, cylinders, displacement, horsepower, 
          weight, acceleration, year, origin]
    
    for i,ln in zip(range (0,9),lt):
        print(f"{i} -> {ln}")
        for row in doc_reader:
            y = row[i]
            ln.append(y)
```

En el bucle, intento que `range()` me sirva como índice para que en el bucle for anidado, recorra la primera columna (el primer elemento de cada fila del csv) y la introduzca en la primera lista de 'lt'.
El problema que tengo es que recorro la columna de datos y la introduzco pero `range()` sigue avanzando en el primer bucle dándose por finalizado el anidado, pensando yo que iteraría `i = 1`, y ese nuevo valor de 'i' volvería a entrar en el bucle anidado recorriendo la siguiente columna y viceversa.
Lo intenté también con algún que otro bucle while para iterar un contador que vaya sumando a cada iteración y sirviese como índice pero tampoco me salió.
**La finalidad del ejercicio es introducir lo que sería cada columna de la tabla de datos en cada una de las listas individuales.**

Comment: segun tu descripcion, agregas la info a la lista lt pero en el codigo la ultima sentencia esta agregando la variable y a la variable ln. lt != ln. por si no te percataste. Tambien me serviria que explicaras cual es el objetivo de tu codigo de formas mas clara e incluyeras la informacion del archivo csv, la salida de tu codigo como el error que salta en la consola

Comment: Perdona, edito el texto. La finalidad es introducir cada columna de la tabla de datos en cada lista

Answer (score 1):

Me guiare con tu primer parrafo y no usare tu codigo, si no que hare un codigo aparte.

---

## **SOLUCION**

Para que tu codigo sea facil de leer y entender te recomiendo separar las etapas del mismo, en este caso, yo lo separare en dos etapas: acceso a datos y repartir datos a listas.

1. Acceso a datos.
2. Repartir datos.

### **Acceso a datos.**

El acceso a datos es bastante sencillo  ya que requiere de solo un metodo `csv.reader()`:

```
import csv

salto_linea = "\n"
csv_file = "02_CSV_data1.csv"

with open(csv_file, 'r') as csv_doc:    
    doc_reader = csv.reader(csv_doc, delimiter = ",")
```

### **Reparto de datos**

El reparto de datos consiste en primero agregar a listas separadas cada dato de una linea por iteracion de un ciclo for.
Segun tu codigo, deduzco 8 datos por fila, por lo que seran 8 listas.
Dentro del ciclo for cada dato se entregara a una lista.
De esta forma, se obtienen 8 listas independientes con sus respectivos datos.

```
mpg = []
cylinders = []
displacement = []
horsepower = []
weight = []
acceleration = []
year = []
origin = []

for linea in doc_reader:
    mpg.append( linea[0])
    cylinders.append( linea[1])
    displacement.append( linea[2])
    horsepower.append( linea[3])
    weight.append( linea[4])
    acceleration.append( linea[5])
    year.append( linea[6])
    origin.append( linea[7])
```

Segun lo que veo en tu codigo, tambien deseas almacenar todas estas listas en una sola
por lo que esto se hace de la siguiente manera.

```
lista_general = [mpg ,
                 cylinders,
                 displacement,
                 horsepower,
                 weight,
                 acceleration,
                 year,
                 origin ]
```

Esto reunido en un solo codigo seria:

---

**CODIGO FINAL**

```
import csv

csv_file = "02_CSV_data1.csv"
############################## ACCEDER A DATOS ##############################
with open(csv_file, 'r') as csv_doc:    
    doc_reader = csv.reader(csv_doc, delimiter = ",")   
################################ REPARTIR DATOS A LISTAS ######################
mpg = []
cylinders = []
displacement = []
horsepower = []
weight = []
acceleration = []
year = []
origin = []

for linea in doc_reader:
    mpg.append( linea[0])
    cylinders.append( linea[1])
    displacement.append( linea[2])
    horsepower.append( linea[3])
    weight.append( linea[4])
    acceleration.append( linea[5])
    year.append( linea[6])
    origin.append( linea[7])
######################### GENERAR LISTA GENERAL #######################
lista_general = [mpg ,
                 cylinders,
                 displacement,
                 horsepower,
                 weight,
                 acceleration,
                 year,
                 origin ]
################################### MOSTRAR FILAS #####################
for lista in lista_general
     print(lista)
```

OPINION

No comprendo el objetivo de repartir los datos en listas separadas y luego nuevamente reunirlas, ya que el metodo csv.reader ya realiza esta operacion en una sola linea. de todas formas, esa es la solucion mientras no conozca mas detalles del ejercicio.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu tiempo y dedicación Marcelo, tal como has intuido (Perdón por no poner la finalidad del ejercicio) mi intención en el código era introducir cada columna de datos en cada lista, para lo cual quería recorrer en el primer bucle un rango de numeros para que éste hiciese de index, y después recorrer las listas a rellenar que serian sublistas (ln) de una lista llamada lt.
A este bucle le anido entonces otro bucle for que recorra las filas del archivo csv con el indice de range (Para que asi las corra por columnas), meter estas columnas recorridas en variables y añadirlas a ln

Comment: Lo quería hacer de una manera automática debido a la posibilidad de que ese archivo pudiera seguir siendo manipulado. Al final es una actividad de un curso de Python por lo que me pongo en esos casos concretos para adherirle un poco de dificultad y en mi novel opinión, creo que sería más realista que estuviera automatizado por la posibilidad que comenté de que se siguiera manipulando el archivo, aunque ahí es una simple hipotesis porque no tengo experiencia ninguna. Gracias y saludos!

Answer (score 0):

¿Por qué mejor no usar Pandas?

Algo como esto debería funcionar:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('path/to/your/csv_dataset.csv')    
list = []
cols = ['mpg', 'cylinders', 'displacement', 'horsepower', 'weight', 'acceleration', 'model_year', 'origin']
for col in cols:
  list.append(df[col].tolist())
print(list)
```

Comment: Buenas Ignacio, muchas gracias por tu ayuda y dedicación, a decir verdad la actividad planteada es para un curso de Python, aun no he visto nada de la lib. Pandas. Si bien me han comentado que de momento me base para Excel en openpyxl mejor que en Pandas (Ya que el primero permite editar y el segundo leer según me dicen) y para csv importando la libreria 'csv' de python, de momento nada de Pandas. Para archivos csv intuyo que es mas recomendable Pandas? (Lo pregunto por la fama/renombre que tiene y tal)

Comment: tanto la libreria openpyxl y pandas permiten leer y escribir un archivo formato xlsx. la idea de usarlos es facilitar el acceso al archivo a una matriz y el acceso a sus filas y columnas con simples identificadores en una sola linea. asi se evita uchas lineas de codigo para lo mismo. como tambien facilitar la operacion entre y en la matriz